# Javascript- Execute onscroll function after a set timeout

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, timeout

So I am creating a page with three div's which become visible upon scrolling. The problem is that the code makes them all execute at the same time, whereas I want that their should be a time difference between the execution of each onscroll function

Relevant part of code -

HTML

```
<section id="section2">
    <span id="one" class="classbefore">lol</span>
    <span id="two" class="classbefore">lol</span>
    <span id="three" class="classbefore">lol</span>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
#section2 > span{
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-shadow: 1px #000;
}
#section2 > #one{
  margin-left: 10%;
}
#section2 > #two{
  margin-left: 37.5%;
}
#section2 > #three{
  margin-left: 65%;
}
.classbefore{
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 18%;
}
.classafter{
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
```

Javascript

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (window.scrollY > 600) {
    document.getElementById('one').className = "classafter";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('one').className = "classbefore";
  }
}, true);
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (window.scrollY > 600) {
    document.getElementById('two').className = "classafter";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('two').className = "classbefore";
  }
}, true);
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (window.scrollY > 600) {
    document.getElementById('three').className = "classafter";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('three').className = "classbefore";
  }
}, true);
```

So, using this, all the three span become visible at the same time. Please suggest a method to give them timeout's so that one function is executed after the other.

Also, can this code be made more efficient ?

Comment: why do you define three separate events for window scroll?!

Comment: According to your code if `window.scrollY > 600` all the span get class `classafter` so all of them are visible at the same time..

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you meant to show them at different times after the same scroll.So what about this?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
if (window.scrollY > 600) {

    var waitTime = 1000; //base time for showing (in miliseconds)
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('one').className = "classafter";
    },waitTime);
    setTimeout(function () { //We  add time to the others waitings
        document.getElementById('two').className = "classafter";
    },waitTime + 100);
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('three').className = "classafter";
    },waitTime + 200);
} else {
    document.getElementById('one').className = "classbefore";
    document.getElementById('two').className = "classbefore";
    document.getElementById('three').className = "classbefore";
}
}, true);
```

CODE NOT TESTED !!

Also, because it is the same event, you just need one event listeners, not 3. But that listener will change the class of the elements at diferent times

Also it would be better if you use a loop to iterate through the elements:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
var elements = document.getElementsByName("commonName");
if (window.scrollY > 600) {
    var waitTime = 1000;//base time for showing (in miliseconds)
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            elements[i].className = "classafter";
        }waitTime + i * 100);
    }
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].className = "classafter";
    }
}
}, true);
```

CODE NOT TESTED !!

Then it would be valid for N elements